# NoRouteToHostException when parsing a String XML document

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, remote-access

I am fetching an XML document from a remote location. This document is returned as a String. Afterwards, I try to parse the String with the java xml parser. However sometimes the parsing aborts with a `java.net.NoRouteToHostException`.

I am wondering where in the world the exception comes from because to my knowledge, I am working with a String at the time the exception is thrown, not a Stream or any other data format necessitating a connection. Ironically, in the exception catch, the entire String is printed without any problems.

**Calling Code:**

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder build = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
...

try{
    String deploymentDescriptor = (String) getRemoteDeploymentDescriptor(webModule);
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = build.parse( new ByteArrayInputStream( deploymentDescriptor.getBytes() ) );
    ...

} catch(Exception e){
    log.error("Could not parse document '" + deploymentDescriptor + "', e);
}
```

**Log entry:**

```
[14.07.14 16:06:17:157 CEST] Could not parse document '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
</application>'
                            java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Keine Route zum Zielrechner
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:243)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:230)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:401)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:536)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:240)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:313)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:330)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:982)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:848)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1184)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at <my calling code, line "build.parse(...)">
```

How in the world is that possible? I thought Strings were always saved entirely in the current operating system (contrary to InputStreams which may indeed loose their connection some time in the middle). Or am I doing something wrong in my calling code?

The try-catch block in the calling code is executed several times for different xml files at the same remote place. It works for most of the files but not all. When repeating the experiment, it is always the same files it doesn't work for. However, the log error entry prints the entire file perfectly every single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that the parser tries to resolve the document type definition that is referenced in the XML document. So even though the XML document is already loaded, the referenced DTD is loaded when the document is processed. The "no route to host" indicates a temporary network problem or a network configuration problem.

If you setup an EntityResolver, you can control the resolution and handle the error, f.e. by caching DTD's or providing the DTD from a local copy. You can also configure your local systems XML catalog to keep the XML parser from having to load entities from the network.